# Sending MIDI and receiving rendered audio through LAN

Tags: midi

I am looking for free alternative to VSL communicating system:

https://www.soundonsound.com/sos/feb10/articles/vslviennaensemblepro.htm

So that I could send MIDI data from master to slave computer and receive rendered audio from slave on master. Does such free solution exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one solution to the problem exists, and it is called ReaStream - it is a Reaper plugin. It can be found [here](http://www.reaper.fm/reaplugs/)
It is free, but works **only on Windows** - although, if you are geek/have geek friend - it may also work on Linux.

VST plugins on the "slave" machine can be run on a virtual VST host. A list of such software can be found [here](http://www.stimtek.com).